# download file from https rather than http

Tags: .net, vb.net

Currently my program written in VB.NET used the following 2 ways to download file from my website:

1) My.computer.network.downloadfile("http://www.example.com/abcd.txt","abcd.txt","username","password")

2) the second option is web client

Now I may enable SSL in my site which runs is a linux server. In such a case will the above system work or I need to change code. Will http in url work or i need to change it to https.

Similarly I read data from php script using webclient such as

```
Dim web_client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient, Info As String = ""
Dim response As IO.Stream = web_client.OpenRead("http://www.example.com/datetime.php")'

    ' Read the result.
    Dim stream_reader As New IO.StreamReader(response)
    Info = stream_reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Close the stream reader and its underlying stream.
    stream_reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```

Will it work or do I need to make changes? I am using VS 2008.

Comment: It should work. But is anyone stopping you from testing it in UAT first?

Comment: I don't know what you mean testing it in UAT. Actually I have only 1 production server.

Comment: @Greatchap you should be working from a test environment. I could suggest you test at the same time a disaster recovery from backups to virtual machine. It give a good the test to your IT DRP. (Disaster recovery plan). I understand you might just be querying the server but you are working in a test environment to a production one. But to answer your question: as long as the certificate is valid all you have to do is change the URI.

Comment: @Chillzy: Thank you for your feedback. The problem is I have no IT department and my company is too small. I have some tech knowledge so I get things done through freelancers and whatever I can do myself. Thus there is no test environment and I thought without a domain name SSL cannot be applied.

Comment: In the url if i remove all http and just keep www.example.com and so on will it work once SSL is started in the server.

Comment: @Greatchap without http or https there's no way of knowing what protocol to use. Before, browser were trying http first, now most of them will try https first. you should always put to avoid any issue. Like I said just change the URI from http to https and make sure the certificate is valid(means you can verify the certificate. If the certificate is issue by a local Certificate Service then you might need to install the certificate into the store. You can google that you will find tons. Youtube has a lot of people showing how to do it.

Comment: I changed the url to https in my.computer.network.download and its working on in all version of windows except XP. in XP its giving error underlying connection was closed. What to do for XP?